# How to reset a simple v-model via a button click

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

In a Vue 3 app, there is an input field with this v-model in the template section:

```
<input v-model="high" type="text" />
```

In the script section, the v-model is defined like this:

```
const high = ref(0)
```

A click on a button calls the `resetFunc` which should reset the value of the v-model via a resetFunc (and therefore clear the input field):

```
const resetFunc = (refVar) => {
    refVar.value = ''  // <= that does not work!
}
```

The `resetVal` function is called from a button like this:

```
<button @click="resetFunc('high')">Reset "high"</button>
```

Unfortunately that does not work as marked above. Anybody can tell me please, what my error is?

UPDATE:
Here is the complete Vue file:

```
<template>
    <input id="high" type="number" v-model="high" />
    <button @click.prevent="resetFunc('high')">X</button>
</template>

<script setup>
    const high = ref(0)

    const resetFunc = (refVar) => {
        refVar.value = ''
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the button to appear if a user has entered something on into it? And, that button will be the handler to empty the input field right? I'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: Thank you for asking, @ReaganM! I clarify my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `<button @click="resetFunc('high')">Reset "high"</button>` you pass `string` to `resetFunc` instead of `Ref`. Try `resetFunc(high)`. Or just `<button @click="high = ''>Reset "high"</button>`.